# How can I iterate over groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

```
DEP ID  |  Team ID |  LETTER   |   Score   | GROUP 
1       |  002     |    A      |    50     |   1
1       |  004     |    A      |    70     |   1
2       |  007     |    A      |    90     |   1
2       |  005     |    A      |    80     |   1
2       |  007     |    A      |    93     |   2
2       |  002     |    A      |    50     |   2
```

I want to run an algorithm in groups. So for that dataframe, run Group 1 first.

Run 1 **OUTPUT**: As you can see the scores have changed.

```
DEP ID  |  Team ID |  LETTER   |   Score   | GROUP 
1       |  002     |    A      |    20     |   1
1       |  004     |    A      |    50     |   1
2       |  007     |    A      |    80     |   1
2       |  005     |    A      |    20     |   1
```

**Run Group 2:** This time if you can see the columns with the same Team ID and Letter is updated with the updated score. Then I will run this.

```
DEP ID  |  Team ID |  LETTER   |   Score   | GROUP 
2       |  005     |    A      |    80     |   1
2       |  007     |    A      |    93     |   2
2       |  002     |    A      |    20     |   2
```

I want to run Group 1 first and then run group 2 next.  Right now I'm able to do this through subsets, but if I have several groups it's hard to keep doing subsets.

Is there anyway I can iterate this by group? What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: do you need `for gp, subdf in df.groupby('GROUP')`?

Comment: I already have a group by line that is running. What I need is to iterate them. Run first group, update with the result, run next group, update and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through an arbitrary number of 'groups' in the following way:

```
for group_val in df['GROUP'].unique():
    current_group = df[df.GROUP == group_val]
    df.loc[df.GROUP == group_val] = update_scores(current_group)
```

Comment: can you help me understand what's happening in the third line?

Comment: In the second line you getting only the lines with the current group value into a DataFrame called `current_group`, then in the third line you are performing some kind of update on `current_group` (using some function you come up with) and assigning the subset of rows back to the original DataFrame.